# Starting activity from thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I am having bit of a trouble starting activity from thread.

Basically main activity starts x number of threads that are stored in arraylist. Each thread tries to find content from given source. If relevant content is found dialog ask if he wants to download it. At this point code works, but i would like to start activity that shows download process.

```
    public void activitystart()
{
    new Handler().post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent i = new Intent(Main_receive_Activity.getcontext(),About_Activity.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });  }
```

It complains that it cannot resolve method "startActivity" (android.content.Intent).

Any suggestions how i could star activity from class that extends thread as same method i used with dialog doesn't seem to work when starting activities?

edit:  Working solution

```
public void activitystart()
{
    Objectcontainer.popHandler.post(new Runnable() 
    {
        @Override
        public void run() 
        {
           Intent i = new Intent(Settings.context, About_Activity.class);
           Settings.context.startActivity(i);
       }
   });}
```

I am storing current Context on static context variable on Settings class, thus the Settings.context

Comment: startActivity is a method of Context

Comment: Yea, thanks for the tip, unfortunately i can only accept it as best answer because i am new to stackoverflow. I blame easiness of eclipse for not figuring that out. This intellij just isnt working for me ( at least with default settings) 1) suggestions are worse than  on eclipse (on this occasion it suggested to use activitycompact) 2) when debugging ( or getting suggestions) howering mouse over objects etc  to get values has range of few pixels (why the f*ck) 3) auto inserting stuff is worse than in eclipse. it is constantly adding ending brackets and what not when one already exists.

Comment: press Ctrl+Alt+L in your IDE to format your code.

Comment: i want brackets to have their own line. Also one of the things eclipse supports better. last brackets are on same row because stackoverflow exited them from code section if they were  on different ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify your Context as follows

```
  context.startActivity(intent);
```